# Why does the threshold for most properties in Erdős-Rényi graphs tend to decrease with increasing nodes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, network

The threshold (edge probability) for certain properties such as diameter two ($\sqrt{2\frac{lnn}{n}}$) are dependent on number of nodes in Erdős-Rényi graphs. Because of which as $n \to \infty$, the threshold edge probability seems to be lower and lower. How does that make any sense? How does small edge probability ensure that the graph is not just connected but also has two hops? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it more intuitive if we think of it as "the threshold is the point at which the average degree is $\sqrt{2 n \ln n}$", which grows as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: It makes slightly better. So for this property we want average degree to increase? Whereas for the property like existence of triangle, the average degree remains constant. So the way I understood for triangles is that the triplets of vertices grow at the same rate as the probability of those three distinct triplets being connected decreases exactly cancelling out the effect.

Comment: Does it mean that since average degree increases we have more chances of finding paths to another vertices?

Comment: So, why do some property require the average degree to increase whereas others appear even if we don't have that? Like giant component, triangles, etc.

Comment: You're trying to understand these thresholds without actually doing the math, which I think is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

The property you chose, diameter 2, is a good example. There are two competing considerations: For two fixed nodes $x,y$, there are about $n$ (more precisely, $n-2$) potential paths between them; the threshold for one of these paths being available (retained, or open) is $n^{-1/2}$.  Guaranteeing such a path for every pair is what costs the additional logarithmic factor.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand it fully. How did you arrive at the threshold for one of the paths being available? And similarly how did you come up with logarithmic factor?